# Returning value from a function using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, windows-10-desktop

I am new to vbscript. I am trying to get return value from a PingTest function below but it gives me an error at the function definition (I am using windows 10).

```
Function PingTest(hostName) 
    ' Standard housekeeping
    Dim colPingResults, objPingResult, strQuery

    ' Define the WMI query
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '" & hostName & "'"

    ' Run the WMI query
    colPingResults = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2").ExecQuery(strQuery)

    ' Translate the query results to either True or False
    For Each objPingResult In colPingResults
        If Not IsObject(objPingResult) Then
            PingTest = False
        ElseIf objPingResult.StatusCode = 0 Then
            PingTest = True
        Else
            PingTest = False
        End If
    Next
    colPingResults = Nothing
End Function


Dim output 
output= PingTest("www.google.com")

WScript.Echo output
```

Comment: An error you say? Which one?

Comment: Its says " Line1: Char 31 Expected statement"

Comment: Modified code works !

Comment: Above code is **still** not valid VBScript (missing ``Set``s).

Comment: I tested it works

Answer (score 3):

Specifying the return type of the function as in

```
Function PingTest( hostName ) as Boolean
```

is [illegal in VBscript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7hbf8fa(v=vs.84).aspx).

**On second thought:**

Typed Dims - as in

```
Dim output As Boolean = PingTest("www.google.com")
```

aren't VBScript, either. And assigning objects to `colPingResults` needs `Set`.